# Restored Project = broken dashboard

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard

We had some projects deleted in Azure DevOps and we restored them, however all the widgets in the dashboard are broken.  Is there a way to recover them or do we have to rebuild?

The dashboard does report across 3 projects, all of which were deleted then restored.

I receive a message about a / in a project title, but the project title I see does not have a /.

I have searched the User Guide and cannot seem to find the answer on this or one that explains the error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryjpM.png)

@wadezhou  Cloud service. The error message says 'Widget error 400: The query configuration is invalid or number of work items returned exceeds the size limit.' (link above) I don't believe it is due to work items because I don't believe any work items have been added (these projects are just a proof of concept) and it was working before they were deleted. I have not tried to create a new widget - I will try that and see if it works and let you know. I'm not sure to tell if it's TFVC or git? It is Agile.

Here is a screenshot of the error where it mentions the / (when I go into the query):

[error detailing /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWQw4.png)

When I try to create new widgets on the dashboard one works and one doesn't:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEyGE.png)

From what I can tell - it seems Git is the default type, and I have not changed it from whatever default would be.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit for the scenario, did you use on-prem ADO server(version?) or cloud service? The error screenshot. in addition, will it work if you create a new widget on the project? Is the project TFVC type or git type?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @DeAnna, please go to project settings -> overview page, check the project name, does it contain the backslash? Try to change a new project name to check if it will fix the dashboards issue.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT I actually went in to the audit trail and it looks like when one of the projects was restored that its process did not restore.  I tried to delete the project and restore it again to see if that would fix it, but it isn't working.  I'm thinking that is the problem.  It isn't even listed with all the processes in the Organization for me to enable it.  I'm thinking I may be out of luck here.

Comment: Thanks @DeAnna, for the process, did you use default agile process or inherited process?  Try to change the process for the project, check if it works. Meanwhile, since it's cloud service, maybe you can raise a support ticket on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report) for help.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT It was an inherited process.  When I was setting it up we may have started as Basic for this one and almost right away changed it to Agile.  That may be why it didn't restore correctly and the other 2 projects did.

Comment: The widget on Dashboard is related to the work item which was defined in process. If the process is incorrectly, the widget could be working correctly. Have you tried to fix the process for a try?

Comment: @wadezhou  I do not know how to find the process to fix it.  It isn't listed under processes in the Organization Settings and there isn't one listed under Project details in the Project Settings Overview [example of Project details][1].  Do you have any other suggestions for where I can find the process to fix it?  When I click on the Board it does say Configuration required.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB0ZA.png

Comment: On the project setting screenshot above, what's the process? Did you redact it or the project doesn't show the process? If the project cannot show the process, as it's azure devops cloud service, it could need product team to help fix it from backend.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT The process was named KaTom.  The project doesn't show any process at all.  That also means the project isn't listed under the process area in the organization settings, so I can't change the process on it from there (I do have another process that exists that is identical to the one that was used in this project and thought I could try to see if it would work).

Comment: If the project doesn't show any process, it could need to be fixed from product team, if you have support plan, it's recommended to raise a support request. Or if the project is not import, you can clone the code to a new project.